# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Attempting to use form_for, I have been getting the error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty." The error is highlited in the first line:

    `<%= form_for @item do |f| %> #------error highlited here
      <%= f.label :Task %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "What do you have to do?" %>
    <% end %>`

partial:

    `<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :Task %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "What do you have to do?" %>
    <% end %>`

Controller:
```

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new
    @item.name = params[:item][:name]
    @item.user = current_user

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Item added; go accomplish it!"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Uh oh, it didn't save. Try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

```

And, the show view(where I call the partial):

    `<%= render partial: 'items/form', item: Item.new,  locals: {items: @item} %>`

So far, my research has indicated the problem could be in any of these files. I have already seen that I could simply write, **<%= form_for Item.new do |f| %>**, but I want to avoid that because all have recommended against it. How is this error fixed? How do I make sure the first argument isn't empty/nil?(I did create an item in the Rails console)

Answer (score 2):

Putting both answers below together, you should use:

```
<%= render partial: 'items/form',  locals: {item: @item} %>
```

And call your variable as:

```
<%= form_for item do |f| %>
```

When saying `locals: { item: @item }` you are saying "access instance variable '@item' as 'item'"

Comment: Right. I just copied and pasted and didn't saw that.

Comment: Just changed it as you stated. However, I still receive the same error message (with and without 'locals:')

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.2.6 (according to the gem file)

Comment: The variable `@item` is also available in the partials. This variable is shared between the controller's action, views and partials used for this action.

Answer (score 0):

In a partial, your variables are accessible without the `@` prefix (i.e. `item`). They are not instance variables.

If you need to determine whether or not a "local" was passed to a partial, use Ruby's `defined?`.